# Unable to use JPEG images in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

My code:

```
from tkinter import *

mah_root = Tk()

mah_root.geometry("900x900")
photo = PhotoImage(file="2.jpeg")

varun_label = Label(image=photo)
varun_label.pack()

mah_root.mainloop()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dm19/Desktop/GUI/tut5.py", line 7, in <module>
    photo = PhotoImage(file="2.jpeg")
  File "/Users/dm19/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4064, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "/Users/dm19/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4009, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "2.jpeg"
```

Comment: `tkinter` doesn't support the JPEG image file format directly. However you can use the [Pillow fork](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) of the Python Image Library (PIL) to workaround the shortcoming through its `ImageTk` submodule. See the [Reading Images with Tkinter](https://pythonbasics.org/tkinter-image/) Python Tutorial.